# MySQL IFNULL "N/A" yields "item cannot be found in the collection" Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been using IFNULL functions to convert NULL values to zeros in my SQL queries, like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(mem.comment_count,0) FROM members...
```

This works fine. I am now trying to use the IFNULL function to convert NULL values to a string, "N/A", but I keep getting the error: "item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to requested name or ordinal":

```
SELECT IFNULL(mem.address2,'N/A') FROM members...
```

I even tried using COALESCE just incase it's an empty string instead of a NULL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(mem.address2, ''), 'N/A') FROM members...
```

But still throws the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the type of mem.address2?

Comment: Does members have an alias `mem`? If not; you cannot use it like that in IFNULL, use `IFNULL(members.address2)`

Comment: @Lex: Yes, members has an alias of mem. I should have included that in my question, sorry. I have solved it now thanks to Konerak below. The IFNULL function needed an alias...

Comment: Please tag the question with the language/database layer that generated the error.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: In English please?

Comment: Martin: your title had "MySQL", but your tags did not. Marcus asked if you could properly tag the question. See how he edited your question?

Comment: That's not a MySQL error. What did you see the error in? If it was ADO, tag it ADO. If it was VB, tag it VB. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is good, but your code is probably looking for a column name? Try an alias:

```
SELECT IFNULL(mem.address2,'N/A') AS address2 FROM members mem ...
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. That was driving me crazy :)